# shell cut command to remove characters

Tags: bash, shell, cut

The current code below the grep & cut is outputting `51315123&category_id` , I need to remove `&category_id` can **cut** be used to do that?

```
... | tr '?' '\n' | grep "^recipient_dvd_id=" | cut -d '=' -f 2 >> dvdIDs.txt
```

Comment: The combination of `grep`, `cut` and potentially another `cut` should probably be reduced to a single command, either `sed` or one of its more powerful brethren - `awk`, `perl` or `python` (or other scripting language of your choice).   All else apart, if the volume of data to be processed starts reaching into the gigabyte range, the multiple pipe operations begin to be something of a bottleneck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, I would think so

```
... | cut -d '&' -f 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using AWK:

```
... | tr '?' '\n' | awk -F'[=&]' '/^recipient_dvd_id=/ {print $2}' >> dvdIDs.txt
```

AWK handles the regex and splitting fields, in this case using both '=' and '&' as field separators and printing the second column. Otherwise, you will need a second `cut` statement.